# "I am four or five in"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions, colloquial-language

There is a scene in the movie Drinking Buddies where Gene and Luke are talking in a bar.

> Gene: I've been ten minutes out since I got here. I had one of these, and then I said, "I'm gonna have one of those," and then here I am.
>
> Luke: Yeah, it's hard once it starts going in.
>
> Gene: I don't know what I am. **Four or five in**?
>
> Luke: **You're five in?**
>
> Gene: I might've.
>
> Luke: Oh.
>
> Gene: But I had a turkey burger earlier, so...
>
> Luke: You're really keeping it together.
>
> Gene: Yeah, I'm a quiet drunk.

What does it mean to say someone is *four in*? That person has drunk four beers? So if I have had three cups of coffee, can I say *I am three in.*?

Answer (score 1):

### You are correct

A person can be [some number] in (to a session of drinking).

You could say it about coffee (or any beverage) if the person drinks a lot of whatever it is or is planning to drink a lot of it.

Alcohol and coffee are the primary two uses of this phrase. If it's used with another drink, it's generally intended as a joking reference to the normal alcohol/coffee use.